# How set up an app to receieve push notifications?

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to make an app with push notification support. I already did everything in the apple documentation tutorial and I am sending the JSON payload from my server but the notification never arrive to my device (iPhone 3g). I also tried with Urban Airship and XtiFy but I got the same result...nothing arrive to my device.

I set my app id with push notification support, my provisioning profile, and I added an `entitlemen.plist` file to my app and I pasted the information in the provisioning profile file in it (everthing inside in the entitlements key).

The provisioning profile also has the " aps-enviroment " key and its value is `development`.

I do my .p12 file from my apple iOS push certificate and also contain his private key.

I don't know what should I do. I don't get any error in xcode nor my server nor Urban Airship nor XtiFi.

But the notification still doesn't arrive.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: "*I already did everything in the apple documentation tutorial and I am sending the JSON payload from my server...*" - Which tutorial? What did you implement already (what is "*everything*"?). How does your payload look like? Write down what you did step by step, so someone can figure out, what's missing...